# Is there a way to keep ajax call running while changing pages?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp-classic, local-storage

I have really big content that I need stored in an item inside the browser´s local storage.

What I´m doing is  that after the user logs in my website, the ajax call a webpage that feeds this item inside local storage, the process can take up to 8 seconds.

The problem is I wanted the user to be able to navigate through the website while the item is in the background being fed. But as soon as the user change pages the ajax call gets canceled.

ps. I don´t need to know if the ajax call was a success neither a response, I just need it to perform a specific task asynchronously while the user change pages.

Any ideas?

Info:
I´m using Classic Asp

Comment: I can't think of any ways except for using FRAMEs or opening a popup that closes when complete.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, using websockets, which your server has to be able to support (such as NodeJS), or not actually loading another page, but loading the content of another page (single page application).

I'm not sure if there's a classic ASP way of doing anything extra.

Comment: I have thought about that already. The problem is that this application already exists for too long and I can´t change much the way it works. Unless in Classic Asp exists something like an permanent section that stays hidden between pages, but I can´t encapsulate the whole application like single page applications.

Comment: Without a messaging service, websockets, or SAP, you can't retain requests between pages and do a page "update". If the call didn't actually return anything, however, you could start the call, and then do ANOTHER call which constantly pulls to see if there are updated results on your page. A hidden IFRAME might work as well with limited success.

Comment: I liked the idea of using hidden IFRAME, I´m just affraid that it would somehow interfere with the rest of the application. Thanks, Going to try to run some tests anyway